$\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is a Vector Space? Proof attempt
I'm stuck at a single point in this demonstration.
Let $ V = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} $, and let $ F = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb Z $. We define the sum and scalar multiplication as follows:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   + & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] \\ \hline
 [0] & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] \\ \hline
 [1] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [0] \\ \hline
 [2] & [2] & [3] & [0] & [1] \\ \hline
 [3] & [3] & [0] & [1] & [2] \\
\hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\cdot & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] \\ \hline
 0    & [0] & [0] & [0] & [0] \\ \hline
 1    & [0] & [1] & [2] & [3] \\ \hline
\end{array}
With these operation definitions, we technically have all the axioms for a vector space, but I have a problem with the element "[2]" because it is the only element that is its own inverse. Does this affect the definition of the inverse element?
"For every $ v \in V $, there exists an element $ -v \in V $, called the additive inverse of $ v $, such that $ v + (-v) = 0 $."

It doesn't say "there exists another element", just "an" element

But you also need to check all the other axioms, what about distributivity? $(a + b)v = av + bv$.

[2]=[1]+[1]=1[1]+1[1]=(1+1)[1]=0[1]=[0]

I really missed the associavity! Thanks

As @Dennis mentioned in the comments above $R:= \mathbb Z/ 4\mathbb Z$ is no $F:= \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z$-vecor space, since the "left sided distribution law" doesn't hold:
$$[0] = 0 \cdot [1]= (1+1)\cdot [1]\neq [1] +[1] =[2]$$
(While $[x]$ denotes the elements of $R$ and $x$ denotes the elements of $F$)

$V = (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},+)$ cannot be made into a $F = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-vector space, since otherwise because of $\#V = 4$ and $\#F = 2$ it would be $\dim_F V = 2$ and therefore $V \cong F^2$ as $F$-vector spaces. In particular $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}=V \cong F^2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$  as abelian groups. A contradiction.
